# Using project directory in include filename

Tags: c++, c, include

I am developing C++ headers only library, lets call it *PROJ*. When a library header is including another, it uses:

```
#include <proj/foo.h>
```

And compiler (gcc and clang) have `-I path-to-proj-parent`.  Users of the library should also have parent of *PROJ* in their include search path.

My rationally for using this scheme is that after installing this library into `proj` subdirectory of default-seachable parent (`/usr/include/proj` or `/usr/local/include/proj`), library user do not need to specify `-I` option.

Is there cons to this scheme? Is using `<foo.h>` without `proj/` prefix is more conventional and recommended way?

Question is not about if installing in subdir or not (there will be `proj` subdir), but rather how to refer to include-files.

Comment: Proof by example: `#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>`

Comment: @MatthieuM. --   I would accept your answer if it was an answer.

Comment: I'll have to improve it a bit then, it's quite short for an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at boost, you will note that they use a similar scheme:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

It has the advantage of preventing clashes with another similarly named file from another dependency.

However, in the case of boost, they take it one step further. If you include `<x/y/z.hpp>`, then you are likely to be dealing with an entity named `::x::y::z` (be it function or class). That is, the way the directories in the project are laid out mimic the namespace organization. It's quite neat really to orient oneself.

Normally, most projects are stashed in subdirectories (and subnamespaces), but the most used ones are pulled into the `boost` namespace for convenience, and thus they have headers living directly in the `boost` folder. There are also some convenience headers (whose job is just to gather a smattering of other headers to pull them in all at once).

You may finally note, if you open a header file, than the include guards they use follow [the exact same hierarchy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp):

```
#ifndef BOOST_SHARED_PTR_HPP_INCLUDED
```

once again because it helps avoiding clashes since it's named after the very file it's in and there can be only one at that place in the whole Boost project (on case sensitive filesystems).

Answer (score 2):

It is ok to have **proj** in the path if you create the proj directory when you install.  In fact its a good way to prevent name collisions with other include files.

The name should not be something generic like "proj' though.  It should be specific to the project.